# How to Send RubyMine Notifications to Growl/NotifyOSD?

Tags: notifications, rubymine, rake-task, growl

I want just send command-line notifications (like "notify-send 'done' ") after some long rake tasks starting from Rubymine. Maybe I need some wrapper for rake? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `terminal-notifier` gem to Gemfile
2. Add few lines to Project/bin/rake file: https://gist.github.com/skydan/f333cd1fc2900f4b4ed7

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about RubyMine but this should do in Terminal:

```
rake db:setup && growlnotify -m 'Finished DB setup'
```